# CyberSource: Retrieve Capture Token from PayPal Transaction Details

Tags: paypal, cybersource

I'm trying to retrieve the capture request token from past PayPal transactions as I need that for refunding customers. We don't have that info anywhere on our systems anymore because, just don't even ask. It looks kind of like this:
`AxjrrwSTQDiO3h+N6P5RABJPE8jCJjo7f4OxZX/x/FO5LcGBSKHWXfwtSx+j1ncoSt3SABJtkGk=`

Is it possible to get that?

I looked at PayPal's Transaction Search API here and nothing in the response says that field exists:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/

I have also checked the built-in reports on PayPal but they don't give us that either.

Furthermore, I have tried the REST API with CyberSource and that doesn't provide the Token either:
https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#transaction-details

I have the PayPal Generated Transaction ID, the dates, our reference numbers, etc. All I need is that Capture Request Token. I will then be able to refund customers using CyberSource.

Any help or ideas would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's a CyberSource token, so you won't find it anywhere within PayPal.

The PayPal REST API itself (no CyberSource) doesn't require it for refunds, only the transaction ID: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#captures_refund